# Can I use two tables on CodeIgniter's model?

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter

I want do receive data from my table "users" and to insert other data into the table "olders", however I only know how to access it from this:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Eixoxy_model extends CI_Model {

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $table_id = 'id';

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}


public function getMarketing(){
  $mkt = $this->db->get_where('users', array('area' => 'marketing'));

    return  ( $mkt->num_rows() > 0 ) ? $mkt->result_array() : false;
}
```

This is what I'd like to insert on other table:

```
$this->Eixoxy_model->create($xy);
$xy = $this->input->post();     //I want to somehow insert $xy into table "olders"
```

Comment: *I want do receive data from my table "users" and to insert other data into the table "olders"*: how are these tables related? what means *other data*? which CI version? did you read [CI 3.x Query Builder Class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) or [CI 4.x Query Builder Class](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible to add another table simply by including:

```
protected $table2 = 'test';
```